Android WebView flickers in HorizontalPager
Today I encountered a strange behavior when I tried to display a WebView using an AndroidView in a HorizontalPager. When the page is changed it looks like the view increases its height for a short amount of time and flickers:

Here is the code:
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) { position ->
    uiState.articles.getOrNull(position)?.let { article ->
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                }
            },
            update = { webView ->
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                    null,
                    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><h1 style=\"color: #000000;\">Test</h1></body></html>",
                    "text/html",
                    "utf-8",
                    null
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp)
        )
    }
}

